# ansible acme create account

Tags: encryption, ansible, letsencrypt

I'd like to handle nginx let's encrypt certifs' renewal with ansible. So I've tried to use the module acme_certificate and acme_account. I have difficulty to understand how is created the acme account.
In examples from ansible documentation, I've seen that a 4096 bits rsa key is enought to create the key but I think it was for acme v1.
This is what I've got in my playbook :

```
- name: "Generate Let's Encrypt private key"
  openssl_privatekey:
    path: "{{ letsencrypt_account_key }}"
    state: present

- name: "Create acme account key"
  acme_account:
    account_key_src: "{{ letsencrypt_account_key }}"
    state: present
    terms_agreed: yes
    acme_version: 2
    contact:
    - "mailto:{{ acme_email }}"
```

And obvisously I got an error :

```
TASK [Create acme account key] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [kb2front1]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "error while parsing account key: error while loading key: Could not deserialize key data.", "other": {}}
```

When I 've checked the account created by certbot I 've noticed json file but I've no idea about their generation.
Does anyone already success in using this acme_account and acme_certificate to handle let's encrypt certif ?

Thanks,

Fayçal

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem, until I found your question and thanks to you I understood that I missed the key generation step (`openssl_privatekey`). I've just added this step and the error message disappeared ;)

This is what I have in my role:

```
- name: "Generate Let's Encrypt private key"
  openssl_privatekey:
    path: "{{ role_path + '/files/key/le-account.key' }}"
    state: present
  delegate_to: localhost

- name: Make sure account exists and has given contacts. We agree to TOS.
  acme_account:
    account_key_src: "{{ role_path + '/files/key/le-account.key' }}"
    state: present
    terms_agreed: yes
    acme_version: 2
    acme_directory: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    contact:
    - mailto:admin-list1@example.com
    - mailto:admin-list2@example.com
  delegate_to: localhost
  become: no
```

For your problem, did you checked `{{ letsencrypt_account_key }}` file content? When mine was an empty file I've got the error message you gave.

You can also try to generate a key yourself, the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/acme_account_module.html#parameter-account_key_src) states `RSA keys can be created with openssl genrsa .... Elliptic curve keys can be created with openssl ecparam -genkey .... Any other tool creating private keys in PEM format can be used as well.`

Comment: I've gived up ansible to handle that but I'm glad if my post helped you to solve your issue.